# Problem Loading SSIS Custom Connection Manager/Type

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm currently trying to build a custom connection manager and custom data flow source for a proprietary system at work, and I'm running into an odd problem when I attempt to execute a task containing my custom manager (from BIDS, DTEXEC, or the agent)

> Error: 0xC0014005 at : The connection
>   type "AF" specified for connection
>   manager "AFConnection" is not
>   recognized as a valid connection
>   manager type. This error is returned
>   when an attempt is made to create a
>   connection manager for an unknown
>   connection type. Check the spelling in
>   the connection type name.
>
> Error:
>   0xC0010018 at : Error loading value
>   "<DTS:ConnectionManager
>   xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"><DTS:Property
>   DTS:Name="DelayValidation">0</DTS:Property><DTS:Property
>   DTS:Name="ObjectName">AFConnection</DTS:Property><DTS:Property
>   DTS:Name="DTSID">{43304F2E-0C3F-4C00-9221-BD88C50EDDFC}"
>   from node "DTS:ConnectionManager".

I have the relevant DLLs in the GAC as well as the \90\DTS\Connections folder. All other connection managers work fine.

Here is the connection manager boilerplate:

```
    [DtsConnection(ConnectionType="AF", Description="Connection manager for AF2", DisplayName="AF Connection"
        , UITypeName = "AnalysisFrameworkCustomTask.AFConnectionManagerUI,AnalysisFrameworkCustomTask,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=e11db2e10378dc29")]
    public class AFConnectionManager : ConnectionManagerBase
    {    

        #region Overrides

        public override DTSExecResult Validate(IDTSInfoEvents infoEvents)
        {
            // Code omitted that determines success or failure

            return DTSExecResult.Success;
        }

        public override object AcquireConnection(object txn)
        {
            // Code ommitted to return new connection; works fine when debugged
            // in the development environment
        }

        public override void ReleaseConnection(object connection)
        {
            // Code ommitted to release connection; works fine when debugged
            // in the development environment
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Has anyone seen this before and have any idea how to move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the SSIS service.

Comment: I noticed that restarting the machine seemed to solve the problem; after your comment, I discovered that restarting just that service also took care of it. Thanks!